# Java - Parsing HTML - get text

Tags: java, html, parsing

I am tring to get text from a website; when you change the language the html url have an "/en" inside, but the page that have the information that i want don't have.

```
http://www.wippro.at/module/gallery/index.php?limitstart=0&picno=0&gallery_key=92

html tags: (the text contains the description of the photo)
<div id="redx_gallery_pic_title"> text text </div>
```

The problem is that the website is in german and i want the text in english, and my script gets only the german version

Any ideas how can i do it?

```
java code:
...
URL oracle = new URL(x);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));
    String inputLine=null;
    StringBuffer theText = new StringBuffer();
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            theText.append(inputLine+"\n");
    String html = theText.toString();
    in.close();

String[] name = StringUtils.substringsBetween(html, "redx_gallery_pic_title\">", "</div>");
```

Comment: What programming language are you using? What language APIs are you using to parse HTML? Show the code which you've so far to get the HTML contents.

Comment: I posted an answer, but in the future, you should really mention and tag that as such. There are a gazillion ways to parse HTML from a site and you didn't even tell anything about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That site is internationalized with German as default. You need to tell the server what language you're accepting by specifying the desired [ISO 639-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) language code in the `Accept-Language` request header.

```
URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en");
InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
// ...
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, may I suggest you to have a look at [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org) as a HTML parser? It's much more convenient with its jQuery-like CSS selector syntax and therefore much less bloated than your attempt as far:

```
String url = "http://www.wippro.at/module/gallery/index.php?limitstart=0&picno=0&gallery_key=92";
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).header("Accept-Language", "en").get();
String title = document.select("#redx_gallery_pic_title").text();
System.out.println(title); // Beech, glazing V3
```

That's all.

Comment: But, if i want to get the text for romanian language? If i put "ro" instead of "en" i don't get the special characters.

Comment: That's because you're relying on the platform default encoding to read the response body. You need to use the other constructor of `InputStreamReader` which takes the charset as second argument and specify it with `"UTF-8"`. Jsoup takes this fully transparently into account by the way :)

Comment: You're right with jsoup is easier, but i still dont know how to set the charset type (for jsoup code).

Comment: You don't need to. As said, it takes this fully transparently into account. It's smart enough to figure that based on the HTTP response header.

Comment: The problem is there where you displayed or saved the character. Are you displaying it in an IDE like Eclipse using `System.out.println()`? If so, set the Eclipse console encoding by *Window > Preferences > General > Workspace* and then set *Text file encoding* to *UTF-8*. Otherwise it'll use the platform default one. For more hints, see http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html